Register Domain with .py Paraguay with an External DNS Service
I was given an unbouncepages website (no-code that also handles hosting) and must add a domain from Paraguay that ends with .py, the only place to buy such a domain is in https://nic.py/.
Unbouncepages only gives me a CNAME record to verify the domain, but nic.py only accepts DNS records to verify.
How can I connect my domain to my website? I talked with nic.py support and they verified the domain temporarily for 8 days but if I do not give them the DNS records by then, they will unverified the domain.
